# Push distinct objects in JSON array in javascript

Tags: json

I have a JSON object:

```
var retrieveSections=[{key:1, label:"James Smith"} ];
```

I want to push some other objects in it like this one:

```
retrieveSections.push({key:5, label:"Joelle Six"});
```

But when I tried to add another object with the same key and label, I don't want it to be added to my JSON object. So I don't want to be able to push this object again:

```
retrieveSections.push({key:5, label:"Joelle Six"});
```

Comment: *"I have a JSON object"* No, [you don't](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247). You have a JavaScript object. You don't have a JSON array, either. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: *"I don't want it to be added to my JSON object. So I don't want to be able to push this object again:"* What *do* you want to have happen?

Comment: I don't want to be able to push another object in my retrieveSections array that already exists. So in other words I want to test if the object {key:5, label:"Joelle Six"} already exists in the retrievesections before making the push.

Comment: Okay, good -- that's what my answer shows you how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want it to be added to my JSON object. So I don't want to be able to push this object again

You'll have to handle that intentionally, by searching first to see if an entry with that `key` already exists.

```
if (!retrieveSections.some(function(entry) { return entry.key === newEntry.key;})) {
    retrieveSections.push(newEntry);
}
```

Or in modern JavaScript (ES2015+):

```
if (!retrieveSections.some(entry => entry.key === newEntry.key)) {
    retrieveSections.push(newEntry);
}
```

But the fact you're using unique keys suggests you may want an object or [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) rather than an array, at least while you're building it, to make the checks for pre-existing keys faster. Then when you're done you can produce an array from the result, if it needs to be an array.